# Issue with pointers using arrays in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory-address

Working with pointers and arrays in C I've found a curious case which I don't understand why it occurs.

**First, I want to describe correct case:**
I've defined a function `void modifyArray(int *list)` where the array must be modified by reference to multiply items by 2 times (x2). Function implementation is:

```
void modifyArray(int *list, int arrLength){
    for(int i=0; i<arrLength; i++){
        *(list + i) = *(list + i) * 2; // x = x * 2
    }
}

int main(int nargs, char **args) {

    int list[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    modifyArray(&list, 5);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", *(list + i));

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
2
4
6
8
10
```

**Now I'm going to explain the incorrect case:** I've defined a new data type `List` and modified the function to accept `List` instead of `int *` or `int[]` as first parameter:

```
typedef int List[5];

void modifyArray(List *list, int arrLength){
    for(int i=0; i<arrLength; i++){
        *(list + i) = *(list + i) * 2; // x = x * 2
    }
}
```

After modification my compiler build fails because the sentence  `*(list + i) = *(list + i) * 2; // x = x * 2` can't multiply bacause of the following error message:

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('List' (aka 'int [5]') and 'int')

I know my compiler is trying to multiply the complete array by 2, but don't know the reason.

The solution I've found is replacing `*(list + 1)` by `*(*list + 1)`. I'm confused because of in second case, when I print `list` and `*list` output is a memory address (same memory address for both) instead of a memory address for `list` and its content for `*list`.

Can you explain why this is happening and what is the difference by using `int *` and `List` defined type?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `&list` is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to a pointer, and is passed as such.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't understand why &list is a pointer. Does not is a memory address?

Comment: @Marco: When talking about C, “pointer” and “address” are both used to mean addresses, although “pointer” might be used specifically to refer to an object of pointer type.

Comment: `*(list + i)` is **always** exactly equivalent to `list[i]`, except for the fact that the latter is much more pleasing to the eye, so please prefer the latter.

Comment: Yes, `int (*)[5]` -- I was day dreaming...

Comment: In any case, the former excerpt is wrong, too, and your compiler did issue diagnostic messages because of it ("warnings").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `list` is defined with `int list[] = {1,2,3,4,5};`, `&list` is a pointer to an array of five `int`. It is not appropriate to pass this for a parameter of type `int *`, and the compiler should have issued a warning or error for that in the first code. The proper argument would be `list`. Although that is an array, it will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and that pointer is an `int *`, which is the correct type for the parameter.

When the parameter is declared as `List *list`, it is a pointer to an array. Then, in `*(list + i)`, the addition is done in units of those arrays, not units of `int`. The result of the addition is a pointer to an array, so the result of the `*` in `*(list + i)`  is an array. Then the multiplication is trying to multiply an array by two, so the compiler complains.

Instead, declare the parameter as `List list`. This declares it to be an array, but it will be automatically adjusted to be a pointer to an `int`. Because C does not support passing arrays as parameters, it automatically adjusts a declaration of a parameter as an array to be a declaration of a pointer to an array element instead, which is supported.

Also, do not write `*(list + i)`. Use `list[i]`. It means the same thing but is easier to read.